# C# value does not fall within expected range

Tags: c#

Hello i am getting a weird error in my application.

there are times when i open my form in design view (form not running), i do not get any error, and sometimes i get an error `value does not fall within expected range`.

when i close my solution and open it again, the form works fine,then start running the application, and  stop it and  open the form (same stuff, it may work or sometime it may not work).

also this does not always happen to the same form, it happens to random different form, sometimes i can get it in form 1, sometimes in form 2,

[image: Here is a printscreen of that error]

Comment: Your default constructor probably does not initialize values to sane defaults.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/8fe36d87-c432-47e7-9303-9b4e8707ae9e/. A Google search on that error message returns a ton of similar questions.

Comment: Often clicking "Show Call Stack" helps to identify where these errors are hidden. Is it possible that you have some constructor code that is setting an invalid value, or is perhaps reading data from a database connection not available consistently at design time?

Comment: This is a pain, I've suffered too. Check all code in constructor, including the design.cs file. Check InitializeComponent method too. Get rid of warnings and errors. Also check the form's Load event handler if you've implemented it. Think of it this way: the designer compiles your constructor and form's load code and if there is a problem you get a this issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. Close Visual Studio and deleted all *.user and other temporary or
   user-specific files.
2. Open Visual Studio and rebuild your project.
3. Open the form and the problem should be solved.

If your using SVN, just use the "cleanup" command to delete all unversioned or ignored files.

Comment: delete all *.user files _where_? And what will I lose by doing so?

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.  Deleted `bin` and `obj` folders, rebuilt, and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Close VS then delete .suo file (.vs\solution_name\vXX.suo). This will close all tabs but you can reopen them.